# How do I make the supports for the roof of the car?

Tags: mesh

Hey I am trying to make a Volvo V70 from 2001 but I find it hard to make the supports for the roof. I have no idea about how I'm going to do it. I've tried it before but it got all twisty and weird.

[image]

[image: What I need help with is that poorly marked part of the car.]

Here's the download for the .blend file.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rLPU7C6R5SLmdcSWtiSf0f1wvV_TTmtH

Comment: While I'm not quite sure what you realy want to do, the skin modifier may help.

Answer (score 1):

Edit mode, use circle-select <kbd>C</kbd> to highlight these corner vertices of the hood.

[image: hood]

Turn on Proportional-editing with the little blue-dot icon at the bottom of your screen.  <kbd>E</kbd> Extract, then use <kbd>G</kbd> Grab, <kbd>R</kbd> Rotate, and <kbd>S</kbd> Scale down a little.

Use <kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>Z</kbd> constraints where needed.

Repeat this a few times to extend your vertices in the right direction, and get the level of detail you're going for.  The more times you extrude, the more control-points you'll end up with.

It may be easier to bring down a secondary view-screen by dragging down on the \\ diagonal-slashes in the corner of your viewport.  Set one to front-view, and the other to side, with your numpad.

I'd also recommend naming your objects in the heirarchy-tree, so it's easier to tell what items are what.

[image: extract]